# Can't add content to woocommerce_after_shop_loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add a second product description to my WooCommerce page: https://alvinecph.dk/kategori/to-go/ from the guide from https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-a-second-content-box-product-category-pages/ .

I do however experience an issue, that the second description isn't showing for the hook woocommerce_after_shop_loop. I've tried to change the hook to woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item, and this seems to work, showing the text. So it could seem like woocommerce_after_shop_loop isn't present on the page.

I'm using the Divi theme, and have created a template for the category/archive page with their builder. To this template I've the Woo Product block. So I'm really baffled about this.

Is there something I'm missing. I've also tried to disable all plugins.

BR
Martin

```
// 1. Display field on "Add new product category" admin page
 
add_action( 'product_cat_add_form_fields', 'bbloomer_wp_editor_add', 10, 2 );
 
function bbloomer_wp_editor_add() {
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="seconddesc"><?php echo __( 'Second Description', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
       
      <?php
      $settings = array(
         'textarea_name' => 'seconddesc',
         'quicktags' => array( 'buttons' => 'em,strong,link' ),
         'tinymce' => array(
            'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,strikethrough,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,blockquote,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,separator,link,unlink,separator,undo,redo,separator',
            'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
         ),
         'editor_css' => '<style>#wp-excerpt-editor-container .wp-editor-area{height:175px; width:100%;}</style>',
      );
 
      wp_editor( '', 'seconddesc', $settings );
      ?>
       
        <p class="description"><?php echo __( 'This is the description that goes BELOW products on the category page', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
 
// ---------------
// 2. Display field on "Edit product category" admin page
 
add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'bbloomer_wp_editor_edit', 10, 2 );
 
function bbloomer_wp_editor_edit( $term ) {
    $second_desc = htmlspecialchars_decode( get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'seconddesc', true ) );
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="second-desc"><?php echo __( 'Second Description', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <?php
          
         $settings = array(
            'textarea_name' => 'seconddesc',
            'quicktags' => array( 'buttons' => 'em,strong,link' ),
            'tinymce' => array(
               'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,strikethrough,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,blockquote,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,separator,link,unlink,separator,undo,redo,separator',
               'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
            ),
            'editor_css' => '<style>#wp-excerpt-editor-container .wp-editor-area{height:175px; width:100%;}</style>',
         );
 
         wp_editor( $second_desc, 'seconddesc', $settings );
         ?>
       
            <p class="description"><?php echo __( 'This is the description that goes BELOW products on the category page', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
 
// ---------------
// 3. Save field @ admin page
 
add_action( 'edit_term', 'bbloomer_save_wp_editor', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'created_term', 'bbloomer_save_wp_editor', 10, 3 );
 
function bbloomer_save_wp_editor( $term_id, $tt_id = '', $taxonomy = '' ) {
   if ( isset( $_POST['seconddesc'] ) && 'product_cat' === $taxonomy ) {
      update_woocommerce_term_meta( $term_id, 'seconddesc', esc_attr( $_POST['seconddesc'] ) );
   }
}
 
// ---------------
// 4. Display field under products @ Product Category pages 
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'bbloomer_display_wp_editor_content', 5 );
 
function bbloomer_display_wp_editor_content() {
   if ( is_product_taxonomy() ) {
      $term = get_queried_object();
      if ( $term && ! empty( get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'seconddesc', true ) ) ) {
         echo '<p class="term-description">' . wc_format_content( htmlspecialchars_decode( get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'seconddesc', true ) ) ) . '</p>';
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does the error still occurs when using Storefront as a theme? Divi changes a lot within WooCommerce templates. And please add some code which shows us how you've implemented everything. Thanks.

Comment: I havn't used Storefront, as I wish to develop in Divi. I've added the code

Comment: If you're against debugging with a different theme, I'm unable to provide help. Sorry.